# How to trigger input's property required on HTML5?

Tags: ajax, html

My question is about how can I trigger the validation of [required](http://developers.whatwg.org/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-required) property without using the submit button

More or less I big a huge form, that is divide by a slider(steps), but is just one form. The point is, that form implement ajax at the end to submit the information that is serialize manually with javascript. So the problem is that the required (attribute, property) is not working, so you have to make the rule for empty input manually. I think is a waste, if you can do that with required.

So I want to bind every slide, to the required inputs.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checkValidity() ( http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-cva-checkvalidatity )?

Comment: I find this as a good option, but so far this doesn't let me focus the required input with problme, I guess I can use this, but I can "trigger it".

Comment: I guess it better to break that form into a simple one